# Is there a good VueJs native mobile platform?

Tags: angularjs, web-deployment, nativescript, mobile-development, weex

So I want to build a small native mobile app using Vuejs.
I understand that there are two platforms on which you can develop native mobile apps using VueJs; Weex and Nativescript.
Here are my questions:

1- Have you worked with any of the platforms? If yes, are they any good? (I've heard bad reviews so far)

2-According to my research React Native is way better than both platforms so I was curios to know if anyone here has worked with '*Vuejs to ReactJs converter*'?
React-Vue: https://github.com/SmallComfort/react-vue

3- Should I abandon my VueJs background and go for Reactjs and React Native?

Thanks

Comment: I've been using nativescript 2yrs + now can you please share "I've heard bad reviews so far"

Answer (score 11):

I recommend NativeScript-Vue. The implementation is solid with a new Vue-CLI template. Visit nativescript-vue.org for more details and hop on NativeScript Slack (#vue channel) for solid community help.

Comment: also quickly try it out at play.nativescript.org (click New and choose NativeScript + Vue)

Answer (score 5):

I am self taught and just starting out on building native apps with javascript. I have experimented with react-native and the new NS-vue CLI v0.2 template. Not only am I sticking with nativescript-vue I am confident this framework is going to see continuous developments in 2018 and beyond that I am excited to watch unfold

Answer (score 0):

You can build native app using Vuejs with [weex](https://weex.incubator.apache.org/)
there is also great article about [Native apps with Vue.js: Weex or NativeScript?](https://hackernoon.com/native-apps-with-vue-js-weex-or-nativescript-8d8f0bac041d)